# Unique badge Icons

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Most of the Stack Exchange sites have their own icons for badges. Why don't we have unique icons for badges in our OpenData site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, most Stack Exchange sites don't have their own icons; only the ones with a custom design do. Usually, such a design happens at some point after graduation from the beta phase (but it takes a while, given the shortage of designers). Open Data is currently still a beta site and with [1.7 questions per day](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51674/open-data) it will take a while.

Comment: Does graduation from the beta depends on the "Number of questions per Day"?

Comment: It did, you needed ~10 questions per day, but [a while ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232), a couple of very old sites were graduated anyway. But they're at the bottom of the list when it comes to custom designs.